# Flutter - android deep linking equivalent of base-href

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, flutter-go-router

I've got a flutter app served for web at `somedomain/somepath/`. I get it to work correctly for web by setting `--base-href=/somepath/` when building it. This way, I can open links to the app that have this url structure `somedomain/somepath/#/someroute` and go_router opens the correct route (someroute).

However, if I want to use deep linking for the android version and be able to open the same links, I cannot find the way in the android manifest to tell it to ignore the `somepath` part so go_router receives the `someroute` part.

I have read [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links) and tried both `path` and `pathPrefix` from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element): `<data android:path="/somepath/#/"/>` with no luck. I cannot find anything related to this in the documentation.

I do achieve the correct navigation using deep links when I don't use the `/somepath/#/` part. That is, by clicking on a link like `somedomain/someroute`, the android app opens at the correct screen.

The modified part in android manifest is this:

```
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />

                <data android:host="somedomain" />
</intent-filter>
```